# How to install tensorflow 2.1 with conda?

Tags: conda, tensorflow2.0

I have installed conda version 4.8.3 and I'm try to install tensorflow 2.1, but commands like

```
conda isntall tensorflow
```

or

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

all ends up installing tensorflow 1.14, no matter what.

Any tips suggestion how to get tensorflow 2 installed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for the GPU version:
`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu==2.1`
or for CPU version:
`conda install -c anaconda tensorflow==2.1`

Also, you may have to downgrade your python version to 3.6

Comment: I suggest that one should do this inside an empty conda environment `conda create -n empty_env`, `conda activate empty_env`. This way conda can install correct version of python that is compatible with TensorFlow 2.1. I checked it works in conda 4.9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: One should not change Python versions in the **base** environment. Sort of why I recommend creating a new environment.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new env and specify the version you want:

```
conda create --name tf_21 python tensorflow=2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [tensorflow's installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#conda), pip is the recommended way to install latest version of tensorflow --  "While the TensorFlow provided pip package is **recommended**, a community-supported Anaconda package is available."

Here is the code that uses pip to do the installation in a Conda environment:

```
conda create -n env_name python=3.8
conda activate env_name
conda install pandas scikit-learn matplotlib notebook ##installing usual Data Science packages that does include numpy and scipy 
pip install tensorflow
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.__version__)" ##checks tf version
```

Note that if you would like to install tensorflow 2.1 specifically, then you might have to downgrade your python version as suggested by @Niki.

In general, we should [be careful](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) while mixing two package managers (conda and pip). So, it is suggested that:

> Only after conda has been used to install as many packages as possible
> should pip be used to install any remaining software. If modifications
> are needed to the environment, it is best to create a new environment
> rather than running conda after pip.

For an example, if we would like to install [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html) in the just created `env_name` environment, we should:

```
conda create --name cloned_env --clone env_name
conda activate cloned_env
conda install seaborn
```

Once we check the `cloned_env` environment is working fine, we can delete the `env_name` environment.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't agree to the implied premise of this answer. Namely, it draws the implication that because the TF website doesn't show `conda install` it is must be lesser in some way, and therefore even Conda users should use `pip install`. More plausibly, the website shows `pip install` merely because Python users with Pip is a superset of those with Conda, i.e., it applies to a broader audience. The only time a Conda user might need `pip install tensorflow` is during the brief lag between PyPI and Anaconda releasing new builds, that is likely premature upgrading anyway.

Comment: @merv, Agreed that I should have been more explicit in my post.  [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#conda) is the relevant statement from Tensorflow -- "While the TensorFlow provided pip package is **recommended**, a community-supported Anaconda package is available." I have updated my answer with this info.